# magento. Fatal error: Class not Found Mage.php

Tags: magento

What i need to change

I have error

```
Fatal error: Class 'ET_PaymentRobokassa_Helper_Data' not found in /.../public_html/shop/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

`public_html/shop/app/code/community/ET/PaymentRobokassa/etc/config.xml` have this lines

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <etpaymentrobokassa>
            <class>ET_PaymentRobokassa_Helper</class>
        </etpaymentrobokassa>
    </helpers>
```

`public_html/shop/app/code/community/ET/PaymentRobokassa/Helper/Data.php` have this

```
class ET_PaymentRobokassa_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
......
}
```

What i need to change? First time see magento, sorry

Comment: did you put `<?php` above helper file ?

Comment: yes. there is all files  [archive](http://vaccinium.me/shop/app/code/community/ET/PaymentRobokassa.rar)

Comment: put config.xml and helper full code

Comment: velik .. can you see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31605/where-helper-aliases-of-some-of-core-modules-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm one of the authors of this extension and I've tested in on several Magento versions, I'm almost sure that you haven't disabled compilation (System -> Tools -> Compilation) before installing the extension. Looks like you have cleared cache and Magento took extension configuration files but does not see the php files.

If compilation is enabled, you need to recompile the source files by pressing the corresponding button on this page.